# onActivityResult doesnt return Intent running on a Physical device

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, google-developers-console

When using the camera Intent to take a video from my android emulator, onActivityResult returned the intent for my video recording.But if I made it from my moto g6 physical device the intent will return null (as shown in some of the images . I will insert my code to give you a better picture.

here is my code ...

```
private void record() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())!=null){
         new_video_file=getFilePath();
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",new_video_file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent,VIDEO_REQUEST);

    }
}
```

OnActivityForResult....

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("CitaTestDrive");
        query.getInBackground(idEventoTestDrive, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                videoUri = data.getData();
                String file = videoUri.getPath();
                File inputFile = new File(file);

                try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap thumbnailBm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream st = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnailBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, st);
                byte[] byteArr = st.toByteArray();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

                ParseFile thumbFile = new ParseFile("TestDrive" + " " + currentTime + " " + nombreAsesor + ".jpg", byteArr);
                object.put("Video", thumbFile);
                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Video uploaded to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

get file path method....

```
 private File getFilePath() {
    File folder = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "test_drives");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    video_file = new File(folder, "test_drives_" + currentTime + ".mp4");
    return video_file;
}
```

UPDATE-----
I did what you suggest to get the uri path. and ....

[image: Update]

Also lock on how i got the path

[image]

Comment: show your onActivityResultCode and full code

Comment: i updated the post for the methods you request Amit

Comment: Hi Felipe, data.getData() always return null When you use provider. You must use the "uri" you created in func record()

Comment: Hi kasim i dont understand i need to get the data in order to upload the video to the server.

Comment: Your record function is already correct. You need to edit onActivityResult.

Comment: change line videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",new_video_file);  and delete line "videoUri = data.getData();". Try again. I didn't check more.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri): String? {
val result: String?
val cursor = contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
    result = contentURI.path
} else {
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    val idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    result = cursor.getString(idx)
    cursor.close()
}
return result
}

val file: File = File(getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse(imagePath)))
```

try this to get the real path for file

Comment: hello can you please do it in java?

Answer (score 0):

Replace with your OnActivityForResult code.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("CitaTestDrive");
        query.getInBackground(idEventoTestDrive, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                videoUri = data.getData();
                String file = videoUri.getPath();
                File inputFile = new File(file);

                try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap thumbnailBm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream st = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnailBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, st);
                byte[] byteArr = st.toByteArray();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

                ParseFile thumbFile = new ParseFile("TestDrive" + " " + currentTime + " " + nombreAsesor + ".jpg", byteArr);
                object.put("Video", thumbFile);
                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Video uploaded to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

try this code and let me know if its work or not.

Comment: Hello Praful what did you change in this code related to my code?

Comment: @FelipeFranco I changed  `videoUri = data.getData();` this line.

Comment: hello Praful what is this line where it comes from                 videoUri = new_video_file;

Comment: @FelipeFranco now i am edit this line please check.

Answer (score 0):

## In my case, I have used EasyImagePicker Library. It is very easy to use for selecting pictures or videos or any other document from gallery or file explorer. Below is Implementation:

implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.1.1'

## You can see implementation steps from the below link:

https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage

### Make sure you have to get permission from the user or set permission in the manifest file.

```
EasyImage.openChooserWithGallery(DoctorRegisterLastActivity.this,"Select Video", 1);
```

## Below is the code of onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        EasyImage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, DoctorRegisterLastActivity.this, new DefaultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onImagesPicked(@NonNull List<File> imageFiles, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
                if (!imageFiles.isEmpty()) {
                    if (type == 1) {

                       Glide.with(mContext)
                            .load(imageFiles.get(0).getPath())
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_logo_green)
                            .into(iv_featured_cover);

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCanceled(EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
                if (source == EasyImage.ImageSource.CAMERA_IMAGE) {
                    File photoFile = EasyImage.lastlyTakenButCanceledPhoto(LastActivity.this);
                    if (photoFile != null) photoFile.delete();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First, create the file in which video raw data would be stored, then use that file to get the path to play that video.

Here is basic syntax:

```
private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 300;

private Uri videoUri;

private void dispatchVideoIntent(){
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    File outputFile = new File("your file path goes here");
    videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),  
     BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",new_video_file);
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && videoUri != null) {
            // do what you want with videoUri
    }
}
```

Link https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics